# Adding a piece of code to a page: Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Okay, here's what I want my Chrome Extension to do:

It's just a button in the corner, and when you click on it :O it adds a tag(don't want to give the idea away)right after the body tag. I don't want it so like the user gets to edit the html, I just want it so when you click the button it adds a tag, and I was wondering how I could achieve this. JavaScript, or is there something else I could use to get this done. Or is this even possible. Anyone have any idea?

So basically, if this is the html:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Some content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Than when you click the button, this happens:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center> //or some other tag
    <p>Some content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you vote down, be sure to leave comments why...

Comment: You really do need more info here...  It should like the "Personalized Web" extension might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, you should do a content script extension.  Content script code will run in the page, and can add a button wherever you like in the page.  You hang a click listener to it with .addEventListener (all DOM stuff, nothing Chrome extension specific), and so on.  Read about Chrome extensions [Content Scripts here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Your [manifest.json](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html) should be like this:

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "A plain text description",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["yourScript.js"]
  }],
}
```

It will inject yourScript.js in every page.  Depends on what are you trying to do, know that yourScript.js has some [Content Security Policy limitations](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) you can change.

Comment: I know how to setup the manifest, and some javascript, I just wasn't sure how I would do it in javascript.

Comment: Ok, try this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp  http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed